# Django updateview form validation error not displaying in templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have an update view in **views.py**

```
class UserProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'my-account/my_profile_update.html'
    form_class = UserProfileUpdateForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user))
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=self.request.user)
```

In **forms.py**

```
class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username')
    video = forms.URLField(required=False, label='Profile Video')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if UserProfile.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            print "This print is working"
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists.')
        return username 

    class Meta:     
        model = UserProfile
```

But in templates form errors not displaying

In template home.html

```
{{ form.username.errors }}
```

When entering existing user validating and raising error but not displaying in form.username.errors . I tried printing form but no errors found on form. Is this the issue with updateview?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

The update view already includes the form in the context. However, in your `get_context_data` method you are replacing the form with

```
    context['form'] = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user))
```

This form is not bound do the post data, so it will never have any errors.

You shouldn't need to include this line. Your `get_object` method should be enough to make sure that your view uses the correct user.

Comment: I included that line to prepopulate current userdetails in form.

Comment: That line is what's causing you problems. The form should already pre-populate the form with that user because you have overridden `get_object`.

Comment: Thanks,..Is there any any way to send post form if post action?

Comment: Yes, in theory you could check the method type and bind the form to the post data, but I wouldn't recommend it. You shouldn't be replacing the form in the `get_context_data` method.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the `UserProfileUpdateForm` already binds with `UserProfile`, so you don't need to change `context` data.

However, I was facing exactly the same problem when trying to give some initial values to the form by following the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values). So in `get_context_data`, I have

```
context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.post, initial={"tags":",".join([tag.name for tag in self.post.tags.all()])})
```

This will prepopulate `form.tags` with a list of tags associated with a post separated by comma.

I managed to solve the problem after diving into the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py) of `UpdateView`. In line 81, they have

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    """
    If the form is invalid, re-render the context data with the
    data-filled form and errors.
    """
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

If the form is invalid and contains errors, it will call `get_context_data` with the bound form. I have to pass this form to the template instead of the form I specified in my `get_context_data` method.
In order to achieve that, we need to make some changes to `get_context_data`.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if 'form' in kwargs and kwargs['form'].errors:
        return context
    else:
        context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.post, initial={"tags":",".join([tag.name for tag in self.post.tags.all()])})
        return context
```

If there is a form containing errors, it will pass it directly to the template. Otherwise use the one we provide.

I am sure there are other solutions. Please post it if you have one. It will help others to learn Django.